# raylib error : Failed to initialize Graphic Device

Tags: c, raylib

I m trying to install raylib c library in my linux machine , but when I compile my file with this command : `cc lol.c -lraylib -lGL -lm -lpthread -ldl -lrt -lX11`
i get this message

```
 ./a.out 
INFO: Initializing raylib 4.6-dev
INFO: Supported raylib modules:
INFO:     > rcore:..... loaded (mandatory)
INFO:     > rlgl:...... loaded (mandatory)
INFO:     > rshapes:... loaded (optional)
INFO:     > rtextures:. loaded (optional)
INFO:     > rtext:..... loaded (optional)
INFO:     > rmodels:... loaded (optional)
INFO:     > raudio:.... loaded (optional)
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65550 Description: X11: Failed to open display :0
WARNING: GLFW: Failed to initialize GLFW
FATAL: Failed to initialize Graphic Device
```

can you help me ?

Comment: That GLFW error is [GLFW_PLATFORM_UNAVAILABLE](https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.4/group__errors.html#ga3608c6c29ab7a72f3bf019f4c3a2563d). What version of GLFW? What Linux distribution? Are you using WSL? Is your system using X11 or Wayland?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WARNING: GLFW: Error: 65550 Description: X11: Failed to open display :0
```

This error is unrelated to GL, but to the underlying XWindow system protocol.  It is telling you that the X11 server to display the graphical stuff has not been reached.

`:0` display should be your local display in the machine (it's indeed the local display you will probably being running, or not).  I need to know how are you running your display environment.  You should be running an XWindows or wayland (with xwindows support) to be possible to connect to the X server.  It can also be some authentication error, or for some reason you have initialized as a fixed string your `DISPLAY` environment variable (this should be the variable that holds the `:0` string)